# Pressing a button using angular causes a v2.show is not a function error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular and I am seeing an issues I can't seem to figure out. I've looked at other solutions for a similar error message and it tends to indicate scope but I don't see that being a problem here.

The current thing I am trying to do is hide some stuff inside a div until a certain thing is true. In this case I want a to press a button and then have some textboxes show up. However I am currently stuck in the fact that when I press the button, the function to set the value to true will not work due to an error. Error is

```
TypeError: v2.show is not a function
at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:233), <anonymous>:4:266)
at b (angular.min.js:126)
at e (angular.min.js:276)
at m.$eval (angular.min.js:145)
at m.$apply (angular.min.js:146)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:276)
at Sf (angular.min.js:37)
at HTMLButtonElement.d (angular.min.js:37)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:118(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:90$apply @ angular.min.js:146(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:276Sf @ angular.min.js:37d @ angular.min.js:37
```

My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="screenPop">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller='TestIdController as tiCtrl'>
        {{tiCtrl.isShown}}
        <button ng-click="tiCtrl.show()">{{tiCtrl.statement}}</button>
        <div ng-show="tiCtrl.isShown" ng-repeat="reqs in tiCtrl.requirements">
            <button>{{reqs}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

and the app.js is

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('screenPop',[]);

    var test_login = ['Identity','userName','Password'];

    app.controller('TestIdController', function(){
        this.requirements = test_login;
        this.statement = "Validate Credentials";
        this.isShown = false;
        this.show = function(){
            this.show = true;
        };
    });

})();
```

Any ideas why I am getting that error on button press?

Comment: because you have `this.show`  which act as function as well as an variable here `this.show = true;`, You should use different variable for function & variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this chunk

```
this.show = function(){
    this.show = true;
};
```

You have a function called `show` and then try to set it to a boolean, within that function. Change the boolean name or the function name.

You probably want to set the `isShown` variable, not the `show`.

```
this.isShown = false;
this.show = function(){
    this.isShown = true;
};
```

Comment: Yeah...now I feel stupid. I guess I've been looking at stuff too long. I changed the names to be more sound and oops.. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisJones -- Happens to all of us - this same thing happened to me a bit ago, the error doesn't jump out right away :D

Comment: No, and even sometimes rubby duckying it doesn't help...because I was still in that state where I was literally reading what I thought I saw..oh well